# Shortest way to invert Boolean if Boolean is unequal to another Boolean

Tags: python, boolean

Let´s say, I have two Booleans a and b.
If a and b are unequal, I want to set a to !a.

What´s the shortest way in Python to do so?

Is there anything shorter than:

```
if (a != b):
        a = not a
```

EDIT:

Can this be further simplified in one line?

```
if (a != b):
        a = not a
        dosomething(a)
```

How could one simplify the case, where I additionally want to do something with the inverted a, but only if it was inverted?

Comment: You can do `a = b`

Answer (score 3):

`a = b` will do the trick.

See the following truth table, where the third column is the result of `a = b`

```
a | b | a = b
-------------
T | T |   T
T | F |   F
F | T |   T
F | F |   F
```

---

For your second question:

> How could one simplify the case, where I additionally want to do something with the inverted a, but only if it was inverted?

You can use the short-circuiting nature of logical operations in python. For example, `x and y` will only evaluate `y` if `x` is `True`, so you could do

```
(a != b) and dosomething(b)
a = b
```

I wouldn't do it this way though, because it compromises readability of your code. Your way is much easier to understand, and not any worse performing:

```
if a != b:
    a = b # or a = not a
    dosomething(a)
```

Comment: hope you don't mind my edit

Comment: @ddejohn Not at all. :)